# How can I exclude URLs within Amazon Cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

I plan on using Amazon Cloudfront CDN, and there is a URL that I need to exclude. It's a dynamic URL (contains a querystring).

For example, I want to store/cache every page on my site, except:

```
http://www.mypage.com/do-not-cache/?query1=true&query2=5
```

EDIT - Is this what invalidating 'objects' does? If so, please provide an example.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the risk of helping you solve the wrong problem, I should point out that if you configure CloudFront to forward query strings to the origin server, then the response will be cached against the entire URI -- that is, against the path + query-string -- not against the path, only, so...

```
/dynamic-page?r=1
/dynamic-page?r=2
/dynamic-page?r=2&foo=bar
```

...would be three *different* "pages" as far as CloudFront is concerned.  It would never serve a request from the cache unless the query string were *identical*.

> If you configure CloudFront to forward query strings to your origin, CloudFront will include the query string portion of the URL when caching the object. [...]
>
> This is true even if your origin always returns the same [content] regardless of the query string.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/QueryStringParameters.html

So, it shouldn't really be necessary to explicitly and deliberately avoid caching on this page.  The correct behavior should be automatic, if CloudFront is configured to forward the query string.

Additionally, of course, if your origin server sets `Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store` or similar in the response headers, neither CloudFront nor the browser should cache the response.

But if you're very insistent that CloudFront be explicitly configured not to cache this page, create a new cache behavior, with the [path pattern](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesPathPattern) matching `/do-not-cache*`, and configure CloudFront to [forward all of the request headers to the origin](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesForwardHeaders), which disables caching for page requests matching that path pattern.

Comment: Also, to answer your question, about "invalidating objects" -- no.  Invalidating objects (colloquially, "clearing the cache" or "blowing the cache") is a one-time operation that removes any objects matching the path-pattern you specify from all edge location caches "right now" (actually, over a period of a few minutes from the time when you initiate the invalidation request).  Useful, for example, if your origin server has inadvertently returned wrong content and cloudfront cached it.  Subsequent requests will result in the response being cached again; invalidations have no permanent impact.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That makes sense. I opted to explicitly exclude a particular path from being cached.